# excel averageifs with date and greater than criteria

Tags: excel

I am trying to use the averageifs function in excel to find the average that meets a date criteria and is below three standard deviations. 
This is what I have

```
=averageifs(R16:R38375,R16:R38375,"<U19",P16:P38375,U16)
```

The P column contains the date range and U19 is the date criteria.

I have also tried array functions with no luck. Thank you in advance for the help.

Answer (score 5):

You need to take the *less than* operator alone in the quotes and concatenate the cell reference off the right end.

```
    =averageifs(R16:R38375, R16:R38375, "<"&U19, P16:P38375, U16)
```

[AVERAGEIFS function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/AVERAGEIFS-function-48910C45-1FC0-4389-A028-F7C5C3001690)

Comment: Thank you for the help Jeeped and edits! obviously I am new to stack.